# How do I get the coordinates of a canvas, even when the canvas moves?

Tags: javascript, canvas

please note that there is a similar discussion where someone tries to find out the coordinates of an image. However the presented solutions dont seem to work in my case.

I have a canvas. In that canvas I have drawn several images. In order to be able to click on the images and trigger an event I would check if the user has clicked in a specific area by the mousedown event. My clickevents are relative to the canvas, since the coordinates change when I scrool in or out. What I would need now is a way to find out the coordinates of the canvas like:

```
canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
console.log(canvas.X);
```

I thank in advance if you are able to help me.
Have a good day
Alexander

Answer (score 0):

You could try `MouseEvent.offsetX` and `MouseEvent.offsetY`. Note that these properties are [experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) but have decent compatibility depending on your use case.

Aside from that, the best way would be to compute it yourself. You can get the location and size of the canvas using [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). You can get the mouse position on click using [`MouseEvent.clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX) (and `clientY`). Calculating the mouse position relative to only the canvas can be computed by subtracting the canvas's position from the mouse position.